# Facebook Like Box - show only 1 latest post

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like

Is there way to setup Facebook Like Box Plugin, to set data-stream (which are profiles posts) to show only 1 latest post, instead of full stream of posts?

Comment: figured this one out?